# Java XML Validator using REGEX and .split()

Tags: java, xml, regex, validation

I am building a Java XML validator without using the XML Schema which I notice is what people do. Don't ask why I am not using it.

I have my text area, I run the "validator" class to look through the text and find each XML tag like `<something>` or `<something else="test">` add it to a Stack then if it finds a matching end tag like `</something>` it needs to pop it off the stack until it finds a mismatch error, in which case my validator class will return "Invalid at Line X, Char X".

What I can't really find anywhere is a good regex that will handle both of the scenarios I listed above. So that I can run my split("regex_code") and get a list of each of my html tags and see if they are all properly nested.

// EDIT

Here is what I was looking for, my brother wrote it a while ago:

```
String expr = "<\\w.[^/]*?>";
String expr1 = "</\\w.*?>";
String expr2 = "<\\w.*?/>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(expr);
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(expr1);
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(expr2);
```

Comment: I do not see any question being asked here.  What, specifically, are you looking for?
What have you tried?

Comment: i am trying to find the best regex query that will find the elements i have listed above. pretty much anything between &lt; and &gt; but without the properties like else="test".

Answer (score 2):

I think that using *only* regexes is dangerous if you want to really validate something like XML.

For instance, suppose you have the following (invalid) segment:

```
<tag> <!--1-->
  <tag> <!--2-->
  </tag> <!--3-->
```

a regex could find a start tag of 1, and an end tag of 3.  Couldn't it also find, after that, a start tag of 2 and an end tag of 3?

To validate properly, I'd recommend doing the following:

1. tokenize your text input into a token stream.
2. parse the token stream to create an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST).

There are various tools to help you with this.  My favorite tool is [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org).

Comment: as I mentioned I am sort of forced to use the regex... I am an extreme beginner with Java so using ANTLR is out of the question for me.

Comment: Regexes are good when you are trying to *tokenize* the input stream.  But, to *parse* a tokenized input stream, you need more than regexes.

Comment: Being a beginner is not a good reason to use a much more complex and error prone solution ;). Trust us, making an XML parser or validator is complex, even more if only using regex (and againts language theory in that last case).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex when dealing with XML. Really. And when you're using the stack already, why not store some extra info on it, like line number where you found that element? This way, it will be easy to tell your user a mismatch has been found.

Comment: yeah the plan is to do the stack which keeps in mind where the error happened. now if only I can get a regex or some sort of search to get all the tags for me so i can loop through push them onto the stack and pop them off once a match is found... that would be great!